# how to have more secure urls?

Tags: html, jsp

when I am using img tag to show the images, I am using ../images/1.jpg address therefore when users have a look at the source code may easily change the address to /images and see all the pictures.
What should I do? or which type of formatting should I use to avoid this, so they do not find the name or actual address of the pictures folder.

```
 www.example.com/images/1.jpg
```

Comment: How about just not serving up a directory listing from `/images`?

Comment: what do you mean? you mean I do not use a folder? they I will have a large list of files in root directory.

Comment: @DanielMorgan Serve it from a JSP page.

Comment: Probably best to not use a porn site as the example URL in your question :] Edited.

Comment: @DanielMorgan Web servers don't have to automatically serve up lists of files if you just give them a directory. Many do it by default, but you can turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off directory listings in your httpd.conf, and in your images directory, create a blank file called index.html.

Also, instead of naming your images something guessable, you could concatenate the image id with a secret string and use a hashing algorithm on it.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, deny directory listing and/or serve it from JSP page based on parameter to identify an image you want.